# SideKiq Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Sidekiq for the background process and creat a very simple application to validate Sidekiq functionality. I am getting success response but getting failure message when calling it through sidekiq. Please help me resolve this issue.

> Error Message : 2018-01-21T15:40:57.662Z 73625 TID-outayy7ac WARN: {"context":"Job raised
>   exception","job":{"class":"ProcessWorker","args":["{\"name\"=>\"Hello\",
>   \"description\"=>\"Hello666\",
>   \"author\"=>\"Hello\"}"],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"866561849a5cd5336ef03cc4","created_at":1516548964.76175,"enqueued_at":1516549257.6588979,"error_message":"When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an
>   argument.","error_class":"ArgumentError","failed_at":1516548964.76448,"retry_count":3,"retried_at":1516549132.7047172},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"ProcessWorker\",\"args\":[\"{\\"name\\"=>\\"Sumit8901\\",
>   \\"description\\"=>\\"Hello666\\",
>   \\"author\\"=>\\"Hello7777\\"}\"],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"866561849a5cd5336ef03cc4\",\"created_at\":1516548964.76175,\"enqueued_at\":1516549257.6588979,\"error_message\":\"When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an
>   argument.\",\"error_class\":\"ArgumentError\",\"failed_at\":1516548964.76448,\"retry_count\":3,\"retried_at\":1516549132.7047172}"} 2018-01-21T15:40:57.662Z 73625 TID-outayy7ac WARN: ArgumentError: When
>   assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
>   2018-01-21T15:40:57.662Z 73625 TID-outayy7ac WARN:

Please find the below code-

Controller class:
books_controller.rb

```
def create
     @job=ProcessWorker.perform_async(book_params)
      h = {"response" => {"job_id" => @job}}
      render json: h
end
```

Worker Class:

```
class ProcessWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(book_params)
     book = Book.new(book_params)
     book.save
    end
 end
```

Migrations Class:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.string :author

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe your problem not in Sidekiq worker but in saving your model because `book_params` is an instance of ActionController::Parameters

Comment: Thanks Kunashir. If I remove sidekiq method then it's working as expected. I'm not sure why it's failing with Sidekiq.

Comment: Try to figure out what is `book_params` in worker (byebug or different debbuger or simple `put`)

Comment: I added put in worker and getting below output-

Comment: After adding put getting output - {"name"=>"Rajarshi8903", "description"=>"Hello666", "author"=>"Puneet7777"}

Comment: class ProcessWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(book_params)
    puts book_params
    book = Book.new
     #book.save
     book.name=book_params[:name]
      #puts book.name
     book.description=book_params[:description]
     book.author=book_params[:author]
     book.save
    end
 end

Comment: Does last code work?

Comment: No still failing. I mentioned that what is the books_param output when I gave put command

Comment: Can you make one more check: ```p book_params.class```

Comment: Getting " NoMethodError: undefined method `book_params' for nil:NilClass" error message

Comment: Hm.. something strange - in post before you've wrote that it's hash but for now it nil.